# Compiling and executing main class which refers to class files in jar

Tags: java, jar

I am a newbie to java and would like to know how to compile and execute main class which refers to class files in jar.

Ex.

```
package com.java;

public class A {
    public void a(){
        System.out.println("In A");
    }
}

package com.java;

public class B extends A {
    public void b(){
        System.out.println("In B");
    }
}
```

Now i create a jar file containing these 2 classes A and B.

I have a main class which refers classes A and B.

```
package other;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.a();
        b.b();
    }
}
```

How do i compile and run Main class?

Thanks

Comment: Put your jar file at classpath and run java -classpath yourJarFile.jar other.Main

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
java -classpath yourJarFile.jar other.Main
```

You can also specify it in manifest file in jar ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try following:
javac -classpath Main.java

here -classpath is the path of your jar file.

Comment: I get this error after running javac command,                     **javac -cp .;myjar.jar Main.java**                           Main.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        A a = new A();
        ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class Main

Comment: Simply use javac -cp myjar.jar Main.java

Comment: Do something like this: javac -classpath pathOfJarFile Main.java

Comment: Check whether you have properly build your jar file and that the classes needed are present in them.