# java execute main class file and include jar file

Tags: java, classpath

I have a jar file and Main.java file in the same folder.

```
javac -cp blah.jar Main.java
```

this outputs a Main.class

```
java -cp blah.jar Main
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main

However, if I execute the following command, it works:

```
java -cp blah.jar Main.java
```

My question is, why?  What am I missing in the parameters?

Comment: By specifying a classpath you're removing the current directory from it. Try `java -cp .:blah.jar Main`

Comment: If you use `java -cp blah.jar Main.java`, then you add `blah.jar` on the classpath, and - assuming a recent Java version - Java will then on-the-fly compile and run Main.java (instead of using `Main.class`).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thx. I'll give this a try.

Comment: @Admins .. note the title of my post vs titles of other posts. To clarify, I would never have searched based on a classpath, as I didn't think this was a class path issue.  I expect the -cp option to work the same in both javac and java. Apparently it doesn't.  And, there is no documentation, that I can find, concerning that discrepancy.

Comment: @Admins .. this question doesn't concern a single file. It concerns a jar file and a main.java file. both of which I consider to be seperate files, or 2.  Thus why I titled my post accordingly.  Remember, I'm searching for a matching problem. Not an ideal description of the problem.

Comment: @Admins .. the 2 referenced links provided in the reason for closing the post do not refer to the problem that I was seeking data on.

Comment: @Admins .. here is the closest matching post I could find to my problem ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528088/compiling-and-executing-main-class-which-refers-to-class-files-in-jar